# How to merge multiple spring boot apps in one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue here.

I created three independent Spring boot applications which needs to be run one after the other, in order. They all are using command line runner to run.

How can I merge these three applications into one such that I have the same functionalities.

I followed this[this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/%40eranda/combine-multiple-springboot-applications-into-a-single-application-649514e7a447&ved=2ahUKEwiGp6HW95fgAhXPeX0KHcJNBa8QjjgwAHoECAEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1DKlVVjaFLkEB7sWtoUqGm) but the main application (parent of all three) runs and nothing happens.

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve it? And also share some resources?

Comment: you can make maven module project so you run into one single project and they internal communicate to each other------------ And add project dependency into another module who dependent on this

Comment: Other and best option you follow the spring cloud communcation in your spring boot aplication

Comment: If it is a question of running the applications in a certain order you can put the three inside a shell script or cmd depending of your platform.

Comment: No @Juan. I want to create a single application jar out of them which have the same functionality

Comment: @harkeshkumar Hey harkesh, Do you have any resources on maven module project, which you suggested?

Comment: i worked so i know how this works but i dont have any demo online to show you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

If u just want to start all together i would suggest to containerize the application with docker.